# Interactive Login to Azure from Jupyter to fetch Secret from key vault

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-keyvault

I would like to fetch a secret from an Azure key vault to use it for an API call. I would like to do this from Jupyter (Python).

I could login to Azure Portal and get the secret manually and store it locally, but I think, that is bad... so I would like to "pop up" a login dialog from jupyter notebook to insert my credentials, and fetch the secret with the API.
Any hints how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now...not sure if it's the best way, but it works.

```
pip install az.cli

from az.cli import az
az("login") #interactive Login is triggered
exit_code, result_dict, logs = az("keyvault secret show --name SECRETNAME --vault-name KEYVAULTNAME")
`secret = result_dict["value"]
    
#call my API with the secret
```

No error handling in above code ;-)